# Are there statistics on denominational belief in predestination and unconditional election by century?

Tags: predestination, unconditional-election

Since the Reformation and especially the influence of John Calvin, a part of the church has believed doctrines of sovereign, unconditional election, predestination, and eternal security in a multitude of forms. Are there any statistics on how many Christians belonged to denominations holding such beliefs, by century? I am curious to know how rapidly these ideas spread and when the number of believers in these ideas peaked, or if their numbers now are the most seen so far in church history.

Comment: Do you mean predestination in the sense that each person is either predestined to salvation or reprobation (Calvinism) or in the sense that believers are predestined for conformity to Christ (Romans 8)?  I know a great many "4 point Calvinists" who leave off on this particular point.